# Change an attribute after the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a problem that needs to adjust an attribute based on the screen width.

I thought that I could use media queries, but those are purely advisory for a tags and then I decided that I would use a JavaScript function which I got working and placed in the `onclick()`.

I know that my function is working in jsFiddle but in my application is appears that the change is happening before the `AJAX` reloads the page so the change in attribute is getting set back so my change is not working because of the page load. I found an `ajaxComplete` **function**:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  var actual_width=window.innerWidth;
  alert("width: " + actual_width);
  if(actual_width < 1281) {
    var h1=document.getElementById('sigsLink');
    alert("Font Size: " + h1.style.font-size);
    var newFontSize = "35px";
    h1.style.height = newFontSize;
  }
});
```

Here is the **HTML**:

```
<span id="sigs" style="display: block;">
    <li >
        <a id="sigsLink" href="#" class="sigsLink" >Manage    Signatures</a>
    </li>
</span>
```

The **CSS**:

```
#sigsLink{
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Please tell me if I'm using the `AJAX` correctly because my page doesn't even seem to be calling it.  Here is my JSFiddle that doesn't seem to be working either: http://jsfiddle.net/Arandolph01/Lj5yr/3/ What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

So Thanks to the suggestion by IndieRok I think I'm getting closer and tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var actual_width=window.innerWidth;
  //alert("width: " + actual_width);
  if(actual_width < 982) {
      var newFontSize = "35px";
      $('.sigsLink').css({
          fontSize:newFontSize
      });
  }
});
```

This gives me a JavaScript error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: what dpes your ajax function do?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807832/change-an-a-tag-attribute-in-javascript-based-on-screen-width

Comment: @vico It grabs the screen width, and then based on that, if it is a small screen it will change the font-size of the a tag element.

Comment: you are using ajax to grab screen width?

Comment: first of all you forgot to add jquery to your jsfiddle. Framework and extensions, on the left, the dropdownlist

Comment: @Diodeus The previous answer changed the size before the page loaded so it was set back when the page rendered. This is to use the ajaxComplete to make the change after the load.

Comment: i still don't get what the ajax part is for... if you want to execute code after doc fully loaded use `$( window ).load(function() {`

Comment: Why not use the $(document).ready event or $(window).load as Vico mentionned?

Comment: @vico Here is the JSFiddle with the $(window).load: http://jsfiddle.net/Arandolph01/Lj5yr/6/ not working either.

Comment: read your console log errors, if your alert() isn't displaying anything obviously there are errors on your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you did to your jsfiddle, but the console displays a bunch of errors...

I changed the code a bit and used $(document).ready event and got it working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var actual_width=window.innerWidth;
      //alert("width: " + actual_width);
      if(actual_width < 982) {
          var newFontSize = "35px";
          $('.sigsLink').css({
              fontSize:newFontSize
          });
      }
});
```

[updated jsfiddle V2]http://jsfiddle.net/Lj5yr/7/)

Comment: @IndieRock This doesn't change the font from 14 to 35 it just stays 35.

Comment: You won't see the correct result in jsfiddle, since the code is calculating the width of the fiddle display screen, not the actual browser width. try it locally

Comment: I have a two screen battlestation so i was able to stretch my browser window way more and saw the correct behaviour. Maybe change the '1281' for a smaller value temporarily

Comment: I re-updated the jsfiddle. Now, if you resize the 'result frame' to be smaller, and hit Run again, the font will be 35px

Comment: sorry, fiddle resets the frame, so resize the result frame to be wider and hit Run. Then resize result frame to be smaller and re-hit Run. Well, you get my point

Comment: How do you resize the result frame window. I tried the edges of the frame that let you control all four boxes at the same time but that didn't work?

Comment: There is a small anchor on the side of the frame that you can grab and move around (highlited with a red box): [IMAGE 1 WIDE FRAME](http://i60.tinypic.com/11grf3a.jpg) / [IMAGE 2 SMALL FRAME](http://i62.tinypic.com/2zgzrpd.jpg)